# Jenkins sonar build get failed with js

Tags: javascript, jenkins, sonarqube

My sonar build get failed with the below syntax

7: var {
 8:     UserService,
 9:     OrderService
10:     } = Core({...window});
                  ^
Seems this is a ES6/7 functionality. im using sonar 5.3 with 2.10 java script plugin. Any idea about this?

Comment: 10:53:35.589 ERROR - Unable to parse file: /ebs/*******/********/workspace/ci-react*****-GIT/react/src/modules/*****/*********js
10:53:35.589 ERROR - Parse error at line 10 column 15:

 1: import Core from '../../logic/index.js';
 2: import * as events from './AuthActionCreator';
 3: import * as navigate from '../../navigate';
 4: 
 5: console.warn('auth/logic');
 6: 
 7: var {
 8:     UserService,
 9:     OrderService
10:     } = Core({...window});
                  ^
11: 
12: export const login = ({dispatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in parsing of `{...window}` which is not yet supported by SonarQube JavaScript plugin as it's not part of any ES standard yet (see https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread).
Probably it will be supported soon (https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-656).

Comment: Any idea when this will be resolved https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-656 ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update  @Elena. We are kind of blocked on dev exit criteria because of this. Hope to have this sorted out soon :)

Comment: Instead of saying thanks (again in the form for the answer) you better mark my answer as a right one, so that next people seeing this thread could quickly understand which answer is right.